# How to properly use two way binding in Kotlin-Multiplatform?

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, kotlin-multiplatform, 2-way-object-databinding

I'm trying to use a `String` variable to bind it into my view.
When I use a model object with a `String` property, it works well. But if I use the `String` variable alone, it only works with one way binding.

ViewModel:

```
class SampleModel(var data : String = "")

var myModel : SampleModel = SampleModel()
var myVariable : String = ""
```

XML:

```
<data>
   <variable
        name="model"
        type="MyViewModel.SampleModel" />

   <variable
        name="variable"
        type="String" />
</data>

<!-- Two way works fine -->
<EditText
    android:text="@={model.data}"/>


<!-- Only one way works -->
<EditText
    android:text="@={variable}"/>
```

The string in the `SampleModel` works well with two way binding but the `String` variable does not.

I think it is because the imported `String` in xml is `java.lang.String` but the `String` in the model is `kotlin.String`. And I'm unable to use the `kotlin.String` in xml.

Is there any solution to fix this? Or is there any proper way of two way binding in `Kotlin-Multiplatform` projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have added a wrong variable in the xml file. In your view model you have created a  variable named `myVariable` of type `String` but in your `xml` file you are creating one more variable here :-

```
 <variable
    name="variable"
    type="String" />
```

so these both variables are different. You don't need to import anything in your `xml` file  just create a `viewModel` variable which you have already done here :-

```
<variable
    name="model"
    type="MyViewModel.SampleModel" />
```

and now simply use this like :-  `android:text="@={model. myVariable}"`

**UPDATE**  :- Here in this you need to use the `String` variable which i created in your `viewModel` because it used `kotlin.String` and in `xml` you have `java.lang.String`. You can simply use the variable which is created in your `viewModel` For eg :- `android:text="@={viewModel.yourVariable}"`

Comment: I just omitted the part that I link the `viewmodel` and `xml` like this: `binding.setVariable(BR.model,viewmodel.myModel) ` and `binding.setVariable(BR.variable,viewmodel.myVariable)`. As I said in my question, both ways are working in one-way binding. so there is nothing wrong with the link. Also the second part you mentioned is not the `viewmodel`, it is a variable in my `viewmodel` of type `SimpleModel`.

Comment: I just tried with normal string as well and it works two way binding. Also you don't to set different variables instead you can simply bind your viewModel class for eg :- `binding.setVariable(BR.viewModel,viewmodel)`. and then use it in your xml with your variable like `viewModel.yourStringVariable` and it should work fine

Comment: You're right. Accessing the `string` that is created in Kotlin class works fine with two way binding. Just like the class I created in my `viewmodel` and used it in my `xml`. Because it uses the `kotlin.String` instead of `java.lang.String`. Looks like there is no way to make the `java.lang.String` bindable. Please edit your answer so i can upvote it.

Comment: Updated my answer. Please accept and upvote so that others can find it easily.